# How to count the deeply nested replies in the reply table using sequelize-typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

`Comment` table.

```
@Table
class Comment extends Model {
  @Column({ primaryKey: true })
  id: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column
  author_id: string;

  @Column
  content!: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => Article)
  @Column
  article_id: string;

  @BelongsTo(() => Article)
  article: Article;

  @BelongsTo(() => User)
  user: User;

  @HasMany(() => Reply)
  replies: Reply[];
}
```

`Reply` table.

```
@Table
class Reply extends Model {
  @Column({ primaryKey: true })
  id: string;

  @Column
  content: string;

  @Column
  reply_type: string;

  @HasMany(() => Reply, 'root_reply_id')
  sub_reply: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => Comment)
  root_comment_id: string;

  @BelongsTo(() => Comment)
  comment: Comment;

  @BelongsTo(() => User, 'from_user_id')
  from_user: User;

  @BelongsTo(() => User, 'to_user_id')
  to_user: User;
}
```

Querying replies through the `CommentModel`.

```
    const commentList = await this.commentModel.findAll({
      where: {
        article_id: articleId,
      },
      attributes: {
        exclude: ['createdAt', 'deletedAt'],
      },
      order: [['updatedAt', 'DESC']],
      include: [
        {
          separate: true,
          model: Reply,
          as: 'replies',
          order: [['updatedAt', 'ASC']],
          attributes: {
            include: [
                sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Reply.id')), // need group!!
                'sub_reply_count',
            ],
            exclude: [
              'createdAt',
              'from_user_id',
              'to_user_id',
              'root_reply_id',
            ],
          },
          // sub_reply
          include: [
            {
              separate: true,
              model: Reply,
              as: 'sub_reply',
              order: [['updatedAt', 'ASC']],
              attributes: {
                exclude: ['createdAt', 'root_reply_id'],
              },
              include: [
                {
                  model: User,
                  as: 'from_user',
                  attributes: ['id', 'github_home', 'name', 'avatar_url'],
                },
                {
                  model: User,
                  as: 'to_user',
                  attributes: ['id', 'github_home', 'name', 'avatar_url'],
                },
              ],
              limit: 2,
            },
            {
              model: User,
              as: 'from_user',
              attributes: ['id', 'github_home', 'name', 'avatar_url'],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          model: User,
          attributes: ['id', 'github_home', 'name', 'avatar_url'],
        },
      ],
    });
```

There isn't `group` in `include` statement. **Try not to modify `sql mode`(such as `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`) or use `sequelize.literal`.**

If `sequelize` can't support it, you can only use `sequelize.literal`. :-(